# "Capabilities" tab in Xcode completely blank

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to create a simple Sticker Pack in Xcode (v8 and v9) which would have In-App purchases enabled but I just cannot see a single thing in "Capabilities" tab, no matter what I do.

The steps I performed, following mostly [this](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev88ff319e7), [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html) official Apple articles are:

1. Visited https://developer.apple.com/account/ and logged in with my one and only Apple ID which is also a developer account and a team agent.
2. Clicked on "Certificates, IDs & Profiles" link in the left menu.
3. Clicked "Identifiers" > "App IDs" in the left menu and then a little [+] button in upper right menu to add new App ID.
4. Used **Explicit App ID** as shown below
   [image]
5. During creation, ensured that (at lease) "In-App Purchases" option is checked. The result of created App ID as follows:
   [image]
6. In Xcode, created completely new project, used "Sticker Pack App" as a template. Initialized the project with following name and organization identifier:
   [image]
7. Under "Targets" in my project, selected the application itself and in "General" tab checked "Automatically manage signing" and selected my (only) team from the drop-down list:
   [image]
8. Clicked the info button next to the "Provisioning Profile" section and observed this:
   [image]
9. Finally, was unable to see anything in "Capabilities" tab:
   [image]

I tried to re-add my Apple ID in Xcode settings, I tried to delete all Xcode-related settings, folders and what not and re-installing (from v8 to v9), I was messing around with dozen of App ID combinations, but there was not a single time I saw anything listed in "Capabilities" tab... Just an empty space. Not even grayed-out/disabled items which I would expect to see if I didn't set them up during App ID creation..

I also tried to create a (development) Provisioning Profile manually on developer.apple.com, used my testing App ID and a development certificate and ended up with this:
[image]

Downloaded the profile and "installed" it. Back in Xcode, I unchecked "Automatically manage signing" and added the provisioning profile manually as shown here:
[image]

Now, the information about capabilities seems correct, but **my "Capabilities" tab is still completely blank**!?!?!

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong in the whole process?

Comment: The capabilities tab appears blank for me, as well. I believe this is expected for a sticker pack. To fix the issue I was having with entitlements, I had to remove all my certificates from my machine and create a new one, as described here: https://ohanaware.com/support/v5Pages/purge_and_reinstall_codesigning_identities.html